# Push notification for an app already in the store

Tags: ios, xcode, apple-push-notifications, ios-provisioning

I'm fairly new and this was the first time i submitted an app.

So i have an app thats already in the app store. I had push notifications set up and it work when i tested it for the ad hoc distribution using the production certificate.

I did another provisioning profile for the app store and submitted it. Strangely after the app got approved some provisioning profiles disappeared . After being in there for awhile they came back but the push notification setting was turned off even the production ssl certificate for push notif was gone.

Now, Push notifications are not working.

Tried generating another ssl cert and the whole keychain exporting stuffs but it still doesnt work.

I don't know if the app, submitted has the profile with the push notification settings on.

Is it possible to add push notifications to that app? If not what is my best solution here?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think the problem was that the devices that i tried had the app built on them from xcode. Because it worked for other devices that i never used xcode with. After removing all the related provision profile from the device itself, located in the settings menu of the phone, reinstall the app from the store then it started to work.

Answer (score 0):

No if the App submitted has not been signed with a Push Notifications Profile , then you pretty much can't do any thing about it, You may have to resubmit an entire new Version with a different Provisioning Profile with Push Notifications enabled,

Comment: Thanks for your response. But am pretty sure the profile had push enabled. So assuming that push is enabled in the profile. What else could be wrong, considering that i had a working production push notification ssl certificate. As i have tested it on ad hoc distribution

Comment: If it was working on Adhoc distribution mode then it should work with Production mode, considering the respective profiles are created with the appropriate certificate

Answer (score 0):

Did you check the server you are trying to connect to when you send the push notifications?

Remember that there are more than 1 server :

```
ssl://gateway.push.apple.com:2195
ssl://gateway.sandbox.push.apple.com:2195
ssl://feedback.push.apple.com:2196
ssl://feedback.sandbox.push.apple.com:2196
```

Answer (score 0):

It seems that some migration script went wrong on Apple's server. Your best bet would be to contact Apple support and explain your problem to them. May be they can do something for you.

Even after creating a new push notification certificate you would not be able to enable the push notification for the app already present on app store. Since the certificate is regenerated, you would need to update your profiles too and then use them to prepare a new version for app store.